# Latitude/Longitude conversion

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, format

I have 64 bit as lat/long (32 bit lat , 32 bit long). I don't know its original format (and type) but I know its position on Google map. I extract lat long as below (in MATLAB):

```
lat=uint32*180/2^31
long=uint32*180/2^31
```

but when I see lat long on the Google map I have many degree error in lat long. How can I convert it with no error? Does any one know this lat long format (or type)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [edit] the question to include the source of the data, and the data itself (as hex), along with where you think it belongs.

Comment: two 32 bit binary data(with unknown format ) and original locations is in MGRS format. how can i convert binary bits to lat long shown in mgrs?

Comment: Just a wild guess, is integer division happening and you get rounding errors? But yeah, your question is hard to read.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification.  It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: The data can be lat/lon *or* MGRS, but it can't be both. MGRS is a **string** datatype, not a pair of floats.